# Hybrid of percentage and fixed size div using increments

Tags: html, css, percentage

I would like to know whether its possible to have an element with a percentage width but to the closest x number (i.e. for my case 200).

The reason for this is because I have a fluid div which is set to 90% of the browser window while I have images at 200px that fill the screen, but because of odd sizes like 830px I am left with excess on the right hand side.

I believe some JS could achieve this?

Comment: I don't quite follow; but would you mind using [`calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-width`, `min-height`, `max-width`, `max-height`. Play around with JSFiddle.[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AWdAH/)

Comment: No this is not what I want, I want the div to increase by multiple of x (e.i. 200px) to a `max-width` of 90%

Comment: Yes this is what I figured would be the best option.. possibly rounding the browser width to the closest 200.

Comment: The answer given isnt the correct one, just the comment which suggests to manipulate the size